# Dynamic form fields and a preview text panel

Tags: jquery, html, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to create a form that has dynamic form fields where a user can add and subtract them as they wish, they're input is then displayed in a preview panel so they can see how it looks outside of the text box. After the user is happy with their input I will add this to a database, each step being recorded against an ID so that they fall in line when required later.

The trouble I have is that I'm trying to get each text input to preview, with them being dynamic I'm trying to find away of matching the input of a text field to the division used for the preview of each step. The first input will update all new dynamically added div's.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThePagan/n4jyW/4/) that best describes what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here's some sample code:

```
HTML

<div id='left'>
<div id='stepWrap'>
    <div class = 'steps'>
        <p class = 'stepNum'>Step 1</p>
        <textarea class = 'step'></textarea>
    </div>

</div><!-- end #stepWrap -->
<input type='button' id='addStep' value='Add Step'>
<input type='button' id='removeStep' value='Remove Step'>
</div>
<div id='showSteps'>
    <div class='preview'>
        <h3>Step 1</h3>
        <p class='stepView'>
        </p>

    </div>    
</div>

Jquery

$('document').ready(function(){

//------------------------------- functions to add and remove input areas.
    var stepNum = 1;

    $('#addStep').click(function(){
        stepNum ++;
        $('#stepWrap').append('<div class="steps"><p class="stepNum">Step '+stepNum+'</p><textarea class="step"></textarea></div>');
        $('#showSteps').append('<div class="preview"><h3>Step '+stepNum+'</h3><p class="stepView"></p></div>');
    });

    $('#removeStep').click(function(){
        stepNum --;
        $('.preview').last().remove();
        $('.steps').last().remove();
    });

//------------------------------ function to auto update preview panel
// This is where I am having trouble, I'm not sure how to match the dynamically generated input with the output preview div's.

    $('.step').each(function(){
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            var output = $(this).val();
            $('.stepView').empty().append(output);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.step').each(function(){
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            var output = $(this).val();
            $('.stepView').empty().append(output);
        });
    });
```

This should be more like

```
$('#stepwrap').on("keyup",".step",function(){
  var output = $(this).val();
  $('.stepView').empty().append(output);
})
```

As events bubble up, you should listen to the wrapper, because even dynamically added elements bubble their events there ...

You can give the elemnts dynamically created ids so you can exactly specify in the callback which element was changed.

Comment: That has helped get the dynamic fields to respond but the trouble is still how to get the fields to append in the right preview panels. I need an append where clause for Jquery.